# playing with topologies

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is any set living inside $\mathbb{R}$. I wanna make this set into a topological space by equipping with the following topology:

$$ \mathcal{T} = \{ \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i : U_i  \; \text{is open wrt to standard topology} \}$$

Does it follow that wrt this topology any function $f: A \to B $ where $A,B \subseteq X$ is continuous?

Comment: :I'm not sure I understand your notation, but if $A$ is connected, while $B$ is not, and f takes values in more than one component of $B$ , then $f$ cannot be continuous unless somehow the topology coincides with the discrete topology.

Comment: If the $U_{i}$ are open w.r.t... then so is their union. So $T$ is exactly the collection of sets open w.r.t... I see no reason to believe that the functions you mention are all continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need some way to guarantee that $\mathcal T \subseteq 2^X$, which is not currently the case. There are two "obvious" ways to do this, you can either intersect $U_i$ with $X$, or you can demand that all of the $U_i$ were already subsets of $X$.

In the first case, $\mathcal T$ is the subspace topology on $X$. It contains the subspace topology by considering one-element unions, and it is contained in the subspace topology because finite unions of open sets are open. Of course the subspace topology does not have the desired property.

The second case is more interesting. There are two qualitative possibilities: if $X$ is itself open in the standard topology then $\mathcal T$ is still the subspace topology. If it is not then it is strictly contained in the subspace topology, but it need not (indeed **will** not; thanks tomasz) be a topology; for example if $X$ is a singleton then the only open set contained in $X$ is $\varnothing$; in particular $X\notin\mathcal T$.

However, if you simply demand that $X\in\mathcal T$ in the definition, then this might work. But even if it does produce a topology, it is easy to see that it does not guarantee continuity for any $f:A\to B$. In particular, the subspace topology of $\mathcal T$ on an open subset of $X$ is the subspace topology of $\mathbb R$ on that same subset. It follows that if $\mathcal T$ is not trivial (indiscrete) then there exist non-continuous functions from any nontrivial open set to itself.

I strongly suspect that the all functions on all subsets are continuous if and only if the space is discrete, but I haven't thought about it.

Comment: If $X$ is not open, then in the latter case, $\mathcal T$ is *never* a topology, since there will be a point in $X$ which is not covered by any open set contained in $X$. And the finite union part is superfluous no matter how you look at it.

Comment: @tomasz: Is that first sentence different than what I said in paragraph 3? But the second one is of course true :)

Comment: You said that it *need not* be a topology. While this is true, it suggests that it *can* be a topology, which is not the case, that's what I wanted to point out. ;)

Comment: @tomasz: Ah, thank you...